# Issue with stack.navigator and scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am using a scroll view on my home screen and the issue I am having is when the user scrolls down about a couple of swipes and clicks an item. They will be brought to a new screen, but now let's say within that screen there is another item and takes them to a different screen. Now, if the user were to return back and back once more to main screen. It will take the user back to the very top of the home screen and not back to the initial point they have left off.

I believe I know why this happening but I am unsure how to fix this problem. So I am using a stack.navigator which are layers stacking on top of each other.

Here's what I have set up for my stack navigator:

```
const UserIsSignedIn = () => {
  
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const Stack = createSharedElementStackNavigator();
 
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
        }}
      >

      {/* Bottom Tabs */}
      <Stack.Screen name={name}  component= {MyTabs} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      
    
       //Popular now section (Screen 1)
      <Stack.Screen name= 'PopularNow' component={PopularNow}/>      
      
      //Game Preview Screen (Screen 2)
      <Stack.Screen 
      name="GamePreview" 
      component={GamePreviewScreen}
      
      sharedElements={(route, otherRoute, showing) => {
        if (otherRoute.name === 'GameDetails') {
          return [
           {
            
           }
          ]
        }
        const { item } = route.params;
          return [
            {
            id: `item.${item.id}.game`,
            animation: 'move',
            resize: 'clip',
        // align: ''left-top'
        },
      ];
      }}
      />

      //Game Details (Screen 3)
      <Stack.Screen name='GameDetails' component={GameDetails}/>

     

      </Stack.Navigator>
  
  )
}

export default UserIsSignedIn;
```

video clip example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NiKHrUfoXANB97zWE9yeAgd0yytpYjOd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please update the code with your homeScreen code and also check if you data is updating when you come back to home

Comment: Okay, I implemented my home screen to the stack navigator and I am still experiencing the same issue. I am not sure if the `createSharedElementStackNavigator` has something to deal with this. Please let me know if there is something else I can do. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I did find the issue. It's the `createSharedElement` I am using. Because when I switch that with the `createNativeStackNavigator();` I am able to return back to the initial point I left off from the scroll view. Any possibility I can combine  `createNativeStackNavigator();` and `createSharedElementStackNavigator();` together under one stack?